# Create a function that returns next working day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that takes a date as input and returns if it is a holiday. I want to create a function that returns next working day based on that stored procedure and also exclude weekends by default.

Comment: How will you maintain the list of holidays? Do you have the data in a table?

Comment: The internal working is not known but all i have is a stored procedure that takes date and input and returns an integer i.e 1 as output if it is a holiday

Comment: Looks similar to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208126/to-find-the-next-work-day?rq=1 The second answer is a SQL solution.

Comment: @richard i don't have a table just a stored procedure that says if it's a holiday on the date passed.

Comment: It's probably easiest to first built a calendar table - with one row per day, and columns for things that are worth knowing in your problem domain (e.g. weekends, holidays, etc). Populating it with 100 years worth of data is less than 40000 rows, and then implementing the function should be trivial.